# google place REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: php, post

I have some PHP-code to add a place to google places, but I get a REQUEST_DENIED error back and I don't know why:

```
        $data = array(
        "location" => array("lat"=>floatval(trim($latlng[1])),"lng"=>floatval($latlng[0])),
        "accuracy" => 50,
        "name" => urlencode($edtName),
        "types" => array(urlencode($cmbType[0]))
        );
        echo "sending to google:<br>";
        echo json_encode($data);
        $ch = curl_init();
        $post_values = json_encode( $data );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?sensor=false&key=xxx');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_values);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        if(!curl_errno($ch))
        {
          echo 'Received raw data' . $data;
        }
```

I checked my google API key and I tried both types: "Key for browser apps (with referers)" and "Key for server apps (with IP locking)" but both with the same result

Is there a way to get more info about why my request is denied? Wrong loaction or wrong key?

This is the data sent to google:

```
{"location":{"lat":4.63762250793,"lng":51.148788446},"accuracy":50,"name":"Binnenspeeltuin+Het+Fort%2C+Kessel","types":["amusement_park"]}
```

Comment: I would say that you don't have to send the request header of `Content-type: application/json`

Comment: I just copied/pasted your code and tried with my key (`Key for server apps (with IP locking)`) and it's working well.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your advices, I finally found what I did wrong:

In Google in the definition of my "Key for server apps (with IP locking)" I filled in the Ip-address of my server. I thought it was an xtra security that this key could only be used from that server, but it's a client IP checker.

So I cleared the IP-area and now it works fine

thanks

Comment: What? What does it mean `client IP` when you make requests from a server?