# Not able to access Google places API using a server key

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, google-places

I've created a server API key in the API developer console. First I did not set an IP filter and everything worked smoothly. I've successfully sent and received requests using my API server key

But then I set an IP filter: `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` to match my server IP address due to security reasons. I have waited a couple of tens of minutes in order this change to take place. After that change I was not able to make any requests - I was getting a

```
{
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

error message.

My server is a VPS server but I definitely do have a static IP address. I've double checked my IP address using `ifconfig` and `curl http://ipecho.net/plain` - it was the same as I type in the Google console.

I am not sure about the example IP syntax in Google console `192.168.12.0/23`. I don't know what that `/23` thing is. I just typed in `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am not very excited to use the server key w/o an IP filter...

P.S.

- I do have Google Places API enabled in the console. I've successfully used the API w/o IP filter.
- I do have parameters `key` and `sensor` and `userIp` set.
- I do use `HTTPS` to send the request.

**Update**: `@KristofDeVos` [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12382965/1574294) that this IP filter is for `client IP address` and it should be cleared. But I don't quite get what this means in the server key context.